# Is it true that `rebase' leads to a fewer number of conflicts than `merge'?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

From time to time I stumble upon a statement that 'git rebase' leads to a fewer number of conflicts than 'git merge', for example here: [Why does git rebase often have fewer merge conflicts than a merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181212/why-does-git-rebase-often-have-fewer-merge-conflicts-than-a-merge). Does it mean that there may be situations where `git-merge <BRANCH_A> <BRANCH_B>` would fail, I would do `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`, then do `git-rebase <BRANCH_B> <BRANCH_A>` and it would succeed? Can you give me an example of such situation?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing  May or may not be helpful.

Comment: I know what rebase is - rewind all commits from the first branch up to a common ancestor with the second branch, apply patches from the other branch, apply all commits back on the modified stack. Basically, change the commits base. But I don't know in which situation it would succeed but the normal merge would fail. I looked it up on the Internet, but to no avail. From my personal experience the are 2 reasons why rebase is better than merge: 1) it doesn't create merge commit (though, merge commits are sometimes useful). 2) it doesn't create commits duplicates when it uses 3-way merge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The technical difference

Imagine a history like this:

```
 A-B-C-D-E  “top-branch”
   \ 
    F-G-H
```

Now **merging** `E` into `H` means: “take a diff of `B‣H` and a diff of `B‣E` and find out how to combine them”.

**Rebasing** on the other hand means:

- take a diff of `B‣F` and a diff of `B‣E` and find out how to combine them into `F’`
- take a diff of `F‣G` and a diff of `F‣F’` and find out how to combine them into `G’`
- take a diff of `G‣H` and a diff of `G‣G’` and find out how to combine them into `H’`

So rebasing is exactly the same as merging `F`, then `G` and then `H` into `top-branch`.

### Now, what does that mean for conflicts?

The rebase method will do the merge in way more steps. This has advantages and disadvantages.

#### Rebase > Merge:

- Conflicts can be avoided by applying the changes in smaller (more separated) steps
- The person doing the rebase is applying (probably) **their own** changes one by one and resolving conflicts therein. Resolving conflicts there might be easier that having to do it all at once.

#### Merge > Rebase

- With a rebase you run a high risk of having to resolve more conflicts, because two changes to the same codeblock that were done in two different commits might result in two conflicts during rebase, but only one in merge. Think about what happens when `H` is actually a revert of `F`.
- Even if you have the same number of conflicts, rebasing is still a more tedious process: You have to open the same file multiple to times to resolve conflicts that happened at different commits.
- Resolving the conflicts might actually be easier with a merge, because you see all the changes of both branches at once.

In my opinion rebase is actually the worse process and while that might be possible I am having trouble imagining a situation where it actually avoids conflicts. What seems quite likely is that you have a conflict that is only caused by a one-line change in `F`. When that codeblock is further changed in `G`, you might have to resolve all of these changes as one conflict in a merge, but you only have to resolve that one-line change in a rebase. But that is not really a difference, as the conflict will only look bigger, but should be just as easy to resolve.

Comment: "Conflicts can be avoided by applying the changes in smaller (more separated) steps" - can you elaborate on this? Do you mean that there are situation when conflict *can* be avoided with rebase but they *will* appear with merge? I don't understand this part - when and why can this happen. Many people mention that but nobody seems to be able to show a real example.

Comment: I can’t think of a real example where a rebase is conflict-free but a merge is not. These situations might not exist. Examples where a conflict gets larger in a merge are easy – see the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One advantage of rebasing is that you can rebase on a portion of the total commits, stabilize, commit resolutions and you now have an atomic unit of progress that can be resumed later. This can be MUCH less daunting. In fact you can rebase some then merge the rest. More flexible.